# Get variable outsite foreach

Tags: php, joomla

I want to create a slideshow to work with Seblod, but I don't know how to get the thumbs outsite foreach:

```
    <ul class="bxslider">
<?php foreach($cck->get( 'galerie_photo' )->value as $fx){ ?>

  <li> <img src="/<?php echo $fx->value; ?>" title ="<?php echo $fx->image_title; ?>" /></li>

 <?php } ?>
 </ul>
<div id="bx-pager">
  <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="/<?php echo $fx->thumb1; ?>" /></a>
</div>
```

Because `$fx->thumb1` is outsite `foreach` - I can't get the links of thumbs :(

Comment: You may need to try moving div inside your li. li is a block element.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work bxlider :(

Comment: how?multiple values will come in the foreach.which value you want bring out the foreach?

Comment: Can i know what will be the value of **$fx->thumb1**  inside the foreach?

Comment: $fx->thumb1 is the thumbnail of orginal image ( on seblod - joomla ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable.But when you are looping the variable will keep the last value.

```
<?php
$thumb1 = '';
?>
<ul class="bxslider">
<?php foreach($cck->get( 'galerie_photo' )->value as $fx){ ?>

  <li> <img src="/<?php echo $fx->value; ?>" title ="<?php echo $fx->image_title; ?>" /></li>

  <?php 
    $thumb1 = $fx->thumb1;
  } 
?>
</ul>
<div id="bx-pager">
  <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="/<?php echo $thumb1; ?>" /></a>
</div>
```

if you want all the values:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <?php foreach($cck->get( 'galerie_photo' )->value as $fx){ ?>

      <li> <img src="/<?php echo $fx->value; ?>" title ="<?php echo $fx->image_title; ?>" /></li>

      <?php 
      $thumb1.='<a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="/<?php echo $thumb1; ?>" /></a>';
      } 
    ?>
 </ul>
    <div id="bx-pager">
      <?php
       echo $thumb1;
       ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nope... i saw now if  use foreach inside <li>, it display more than 3 images ( duplicate first and last ).... I think i have problem with foreach in slider...

Comment: if i use only simple foreach, it display 3 images, that's corect. 

<?php foreach($cck->get( 'galerie_photo' )->value as $fx){ ?>
 <img src="/<?php echo $fx->value; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fx->image_alt; ?>" title ="<?php echo $fx->image_title; ?>" />
 <?php } ?>

Comment: so you got the solution

Comment: Nope... i must find the reason why foreach in ul tag it's display more than 3 images that i have...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$html = '';
<ul class="bxslider">

<?php 
  $i = 0;
 foreach($cck->get( 'galerie_photo' )->value as $fx){ ?>

  <li> <img src="/<?php echo $fx->value; ?>" title ="<?php echo $fx->image_title; ?>" /></li>

  $html.=" <a data-slide-index='{$i}' href=''><img src='/{$fx->thumb1}' /></a>";

 <?php $i++; } ?>
 </ul>
<div id="bx-pager">
  <?php echo $html; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code but not working, i don't know why.

Comment: what issue now, Please inspect the html

Comment: What is the output $fx->thumb1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code : 
Hope it helps.

```
$img_thumb = array();
    <ul class="bxslider">
    <?php foreach($cck->get( 'galerie_photo' )->value as $fx){ ?>

      <li> <img src="/<?php echo $fx->value; ?>" title ="<?php echo $fx->image_title; ?>" /></li>
    $img_thumb[] =  $fx->thumb1;
     <?php } ?>
     </ul>
    <div id="bx-pager">
      <a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="/<?php echo $img_thumb; ?>" /></a>
    </div>
```